# WordPress Custom Page Submit Form

Tags: php, wordpress, submit

I'm trying to write a simple script to write some data to mysql then read it. My code is working without a problem alone but I'm trying to use it inside a WordPress page, this is the point problem starts.

I have created a template file for WordPress, and using this template to create the page. Page shows up without a problem but whenever I try to submit the form inside it (my custom php form) it forwards me to index.php .

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
<span>Enter Your Code : </span><br/>
<input type="text" name="sha256"><br/>
<p align = right><input type="submit" name="shaSubmit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
```

this is my form (inside custom php), and as you can see it posts the data to itself. At the the start of my custom php code I have

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
```

But it doesn't matter, as soon as I click on button, it forward me to domain.com/index.php

Btw, this custom php is on a page with such url domain.com/custompage/

How can make this form work ?

ps. Code above is for reading from mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change 2 things.

(1)make  action=""

don't need to use  `action=" echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])"`

(2)if(isset($_POST['shaSubmit'])){

the code ....

}

Comment: thank you, action="" was the problem. ($_POST['shaSubmit'] was correct in the actual code)

Answer (score 1):

You're using the following conditional statement `if(isset($_POST['Submit']))` along with the submit button's named element `name="shaSubmit"`.

You need to make those match.

Either by changing the name of your submit button to `name="Submit"`

or by changing your conditional statement to `if(isset($_POST['shaSubmit']))`

which is why your code is failing because of the conditional statement you've set is relying on a form element named "shaSubmit".